# Overwriting files; changing the content but keeping the filename

Tags: python

This'll be a bit long winded but might be best to explain the scenario first...

We have a number of BI visualizations that are generated each month for management reporting. Just over 400 images are taken each month and automatically placed in a directory using WKHTMLTOIMAGE. These images are automatically updated in to various PowerPoint presentations and emailed off to the relevant teams. All of this "generally" works fine and has removed much of the tedious manual work.

The problem occurs when one of these visualizations fails to update. At the moment there is no way of checking, other than to open up each visualization and compare it to the image that has just been extracted.

If 399 of the 400 images work, and the 400th doesn't, PowerPoint would still be populated using the previously loaded (400th) image due to the way the "Link to File" function works in PowerPoint.

What I'd like to do is use an example image (check.jpg) to overwrite all of the existing images but still keeping their original file names. That way when the monthly report is run if one of them doesn't work the PowerPoint would have still been updated with this check.jpg image which would stand out as something we would need to rerun manually.

I can't seem to find anything along the lines of what I'm looking for. I can list all of the filenames, move them, overwrite them etc but not sure how I'd do it (or even if it's the right way to do it) with the scenario I'm thinking of. If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Opening a file for writing doesn't change the filename:

```
with open("path/to/check.jpg", "rb") as src, open("path/to/image.jpg", "wb") as dest:
    dest.write(src.read())
```

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you. Just a quick one; when I enter the above it'll hang until I hit enter again, then when I do it'll print 10747. It works but I just don't understand what/why I see that?

Comment: "when I enter the above" => in an interactive python shell ? yes, that's the expected behaviour - the shell waits until you've finished the indented block (else how could it know you don't have another line to add to the block ?), and prints the value of the last expression (in this case the number of bytes written by `dest.write()`).